# Decreasing a Filled Rectangle's height from top

Tags: java, swing, size, jcomponent

I am using a paintComponent Class in a project of mine, and I am currently wondering how I can decrease the size of the rectangle from the top making it's way downwards.

This is the part of the code:

```
public Battery(){

    super();
    firstTime = true;
    f = new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 14);
    m = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getFontMetrics(f);
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

    if(firstTime){

        firstTime = false;
        batteryLevel = 1 +  this.getHeight();
        decr = batteryLevel / 20; 

    }else{

        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(1, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());

        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.fillRect(1, 0, this.getWidth(), batteryLevel);

        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.setFont(f);
        g.drawString("TEST", (getWidth() - m.stringWidth("TEST")) / 2 , this.getHeight() / 2);
    }

}

public void decreaseBatteryLevel(){

    batteryLevel -= decr; 
    this.repaint();

}
```

PS. Sorry if I did something wrong, I'm new to this forum.

Answer (score 1):

Instead

```
    g.fillRect(1, 0, this.getWidth(), batteryLevel);
```

Do

```
    g.fillRect(1, batteryLevel, this.getWidth(), getHeight() - batteryLevel);
```

Also maybe `repaint(50L)` instead of `repaint()`.

---

***If your question meant: how to animate a change in the battery level.***

Use a javax.swing.Timer:

```
    int toPaintBatteryLevel = batteryLevel;
    // In the paintComponent paint upto toPaintBatteryLevel.

    Timer timer = new Timer(100, new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (toPaintBatteryLevl == batteryLevel) {
                return;
            }
            if (toPaintBatteryLevl > batteryLevel) {
                --toPaintBatteryLevel; // Animate slowly
            } else {
                toPaintBatteryLevel = batteryLevel; // Change immediately
            }
            repaint(50L);
        };

    });

    timer.start();
```

For ease of coding, there is a permanent timer. And externally one changes the batteryLevel,
and the time determines the toPaintBatteryLevel, which paintComponent uses to paint.

Comment: I'm sorry but I actually need the rectangle to descend downwards and not ascend upwards.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood. One remark: the code in the else-part should always be executed, also the first time; bring it outside the if-statement.

Answer (score 1):

As you want the visible battery level to descend you will want to increase your Y co-ordinate in relation to the value of `batteryLevel`. You could use:

```
g.fillRect(1, getHeight() - batteryLevel, getWidth(), batteryLevel);
```